# A question related to the continuity of lower limit topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

While self-studying topology from C. Wayne Patty, I am unable to think of ways on how to solve this question.

> [image]

Please note that I am only unable to solve (b) and (c). I tried a lot of sets but couldn't find any.

So I'm asking for your help with solving any of the two.

Comment: Since $f$ is the identity function, the question is essentially asking you to find a set that is closed in $\mathscr F$ but not $\mathscr U$. Can you think of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\overline{[0,1)}=[0,1)$ in $\Bbb R_l$ (or $\mathcal{T}$), but $[0,1)=f[[0,1)]$ has closure $[0,1]$ in $\mathcal{U}$.

The same example set works for the inverse too.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

(b) The set $A:=[0,1)$ does the job.

(c) The set $B:=[0,1)$ does the job.